# What type of sword does Yoshimitsu use in Tekken: DR?

Tags: tekken-5

For one of my upcoming projects, I need to be able to create Yoshimitsu's sword, and if it varies from game-to-game, I'm talking about the one shown in Tekken 5: Dark Resurrection, used by the more skeletal appearence. Some images can be seen here:

[image: Yoshimitsu T5 Sword]
[image: Yoshimitsu T5 Sword]
[image: Yoshimitsu T5 Sword]
[image: Yoshimitsu T5 Sword]
I'm looking for the exact historical type of sword used, so I can then research it.

By the way, before any downvotes, this is about the lore of the game.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about real life sword identification, which has nothing to do with gaming.

Comment: @Frank I thought it would be find because it's talking about the lore of the game, which I assume is accepted here. Would it be better if I asked it on history.stackexchange?

Comment: How is this lore?  You're not asking for in-game information, you're specifically asking for real world equivalents.  That's off-topic, as it has nothing to do with gaming expertise.

Answer (score 4):

From the [Fandom Wiki for Yoshimitsu](http://tekken.wikia.com/wiki/Yoshimitsu), it is mentioned a few times that the sword resembles that of a [tachi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tachi) that has been modified in different ways (presumably across the games like you've mentioned):

> While his sword is always a Japanese sword and is the same sword passed down through many generations, it never keeps the same appearance and is usually depicted as a tachi, although modified in certain ways.

Below is an image of a tachi I found on the internet:

[image: Tachi]

<sub><sub>[Image Source](http://www.swordzone.com/shop/step1.php?number=111)</sub></sub>

It certainly looks like the sword used in the game except in the last picture, where Yoshimitsu's sword has a loop at the bottom of the grip.  This is probably one of those modifications mentioned.

Comment: Using a katana would make more sense since tachis were mostly used from horsebacks ... gaming lore is weird.